# How to print current number of items stored on top of the list of all elements in C?

Tags: c

When i try to printf(" O");   i want it print 10 instead which is the number of elements not print something that many times. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    while(fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, f)==1)
    {
      printf(" O");  
    }
```

Comment: Well, then instead of calling `printf` just increment a counter and then print the counter after the loop.

Comment: Please don't edit your questions to the point they're no longer recognisable

Comment: What I wonder is, your code seems pretty advanced (you even check the returned pointer of `fopen()` for a null pointer), but then again you ask for how to print a counter. (Well I think you got the code from someone else) - You should read a good C starting book and learn the basics first before continuing. Take a look at f.e. K&R [here](https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf) or Modern C [here](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/).

Comment: I know it might seem like that but no i  wrote the code myself. The thing is i need more practice and the last time i used a counter was a while ago, also i'm really tired right now and have a deadline thus can't thing straightly

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
while(fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, f)==1)
{
  i++;
}
printf("%d\n", i);
```